# Check if MKPolyline overlay already exists

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkpolyline

How can I check if a polyline has already been added to the map?

I've tried the following code, but it doesnt seem to work

```
for (MKPolyline *feature1 in self.mapView.overlays) {

       NSLog(@"feature1.title: %@", feature1.title);
       NSLog(@"Polu.title: %@", polu.title);

       if (![feature1.title isEqualToString:polu.title]) {
             NSLog(@"NOT");
             [self.mapView addOverlay:polu];
       }
       else {
             NSLog(@"Already added");
       }
      }
     }
```

I've also tried this:

```
if (![self.mapView.overlays containsObject:polu]) {
    NSLog(@"NOT");
   [self.mapView addOverlay:polu];
}
```

Comment: With the for-loop, shouldn't you check _all_ overlays before deciding whether it's added or not?  Right now, it decides based on the result of the _first_ overlay.  The second try probably doesn't work because `polu` was not the original object added.

Comment: Can you help me fix the for method? Should i compare the array of overlays with array from self.mapview.overlays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current `for` loop assumes the overlay exists or doesn't exist as soon as it finds *one* other overlay whose title doesn't match.

But at that point, the `for` loop might not have checked the remaining overlays (one of which might be the overlay you're looking for).

For example:

- Assume there are already 4 overlays on the map with the titles A, B, C, and D.
- Assume the overlay you want to check for (`polu`) has the title C.
- The first overlay checked is A.  Since A does not match C, the existing code immediately adds another overlay named C.
- Then the `for` loop continues and looks at B.  Again, since B does not match C, the existing code adds another overlay named C.
- Then the loop continues, looks at C, and logs "already added".
- Then the loop continues, looks at D, sees it doesn't match C, and adds another overlay.

Instead, you want to stop the loop when a matching title is found and if the loop ends with no match found, *then* add the overlay.

Example:

```
BOOL poluExists = NO;

for (MKPolyline *feature1 in self.mapView.overlays) {

    NSLog(@"feature1.title: %@", feature1.title);
    NSLog(@"Polu.title: %@", polu.title);

    //STOP looping if titles MATCH...
    if ([feature1.title isEqualToString:polu.title]) {
        poluExists = YES;
        break;
    }
}

//AFTER the loop, we know whether polu.title exists or not.
//If it existed, loop would have been stopped and we come here.
//If it didn't exist, loop would have checked all overlays and we come here.
if (poluExists) {
    NSLog(@"Already added");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"NOT");
    [self.mapView addOverlay:polu];
}
```

In the second example in the question, `containsObject:` will only work if `polu` was the original object that was given the first time `addOverlay` was called because in this case, `containsObject:` will compare pointer addresses and not the `title` property of the overlays.